# Maven profile does not work with files exclusion

Tags: java, maven

My problem is that I want to exclude some files from generated **.jar** using maven only while using specific profile.

Exclusion of files work`s fine while not nested in any profile:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/abc.txt</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

But if I try to use profile like this:

```
<profile>
        <id>profile</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                ...
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Than the exclusion does not happen. I am generating jar during application build in Idea.

Please is there any way to make it work like this?

Comment: Did you activate the profile?

Comment: Yes, i did, also made sure if it`s the same, and on the other hand, other profiles work fine, but i am using only different application.properties in them.

Comment: If those files are application.properties (I suppose Spring Boot ?) you should not use any maven profiles... furthermore if those files should not being made part of the jar remove them...simply...

Comment: other profiles just switch application.properties for their, this new profile should exclude one file from resources while generating jar. And i cannot simply remove the file, because it`s used when on different profile.